# Como realizar reemplazos en una string solo si no esta precedido y sucedido por una substring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, replace

```py
import re, datetime

input_text = "Alrededor de las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm 2022_-_02_-_18 , quizas cerca del 2022_-_02_-_18 llega el avion, pero no (2022_-_02_-_18 20:16 pm) a las (2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)"

print(repr(input_text)) # --> output


input_date_structure = r"(?P<year>\d*)_-_(?P<month>\d{2})_-_(?P<startDay>\d{2})"

identify_only_date_regex_00 = input_date_structure + r"[\s|]*" + r"(\b\d{2}:\d{2}[\s|]*[ap]m)?" #to identify if there is a time after  the date
identify_only_date_regex_01 = r"(\b\d{2}:\d{2}[\s|]*[ap]m)?" + r"[\s|]*" + input_date_structure #to identify if there is a time before the date


date_restructuring_structure = r"\g<year>_-_\g<month>_-_\g<startDay>"
restructuring_only_date = lambda x: x.group() if x.group(1) else "(" + fr"{x.expand(date_restructuring_structure)}" + " 00:00 am)"

#do the replace with re.sub() method and the regex patterns instructions
input_text = re.sub(identify_only_date_regex_00, restructuring_only_date, input_text)
input_text = re.sub(identify_only_date_regex_01, restructuring_only_date, input_text)

#print output
print(repr(input_text)) # --> output
```

El **output erroneo** que estoy obteniendo:

```
'Alrededor de las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm 2022_-_02_-_18 , quizas cerca del(2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am) llega el avion, pero no ((2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am) 20:16 pm) a las ((2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am) 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)''
```

El **output correcto**, en donde solo las fechas que no estaban precedidas ni sucedidas por horas **hh:mm am or pm**, indicadas como `r"(\d{2}:\d{2}[\s|]*[ap]m)?"`, son modificadas:

```
"Alrededor de las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm 2022_-_02_-_18 , quizas cerca del (2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am) llega el avion, pero no (2022_-_02_-_18 20:16 pm) a las (2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)"
```

No entiendo porque esta fallando, al menos creo que estoy condicionando bien mis regex usando `\b` y `?`

En este ejemplo podemos ver los 3 casos posibles, donde la fecha va precedida de la hora, luego uno donde solo va la fecha, y finalmente hay una fecha seguida de la hora. Y el único caso en el que debe hacer el reemplazo es cuando la fecha está sola (sin la indicación de hora **hh:mm am o pm**)

No debe reemplazar
`"sdsdds 2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am sdsddssd2`

No debe reemplazar
`"sdsdsd 00:16 am 2022_-_02_-_18 sdsdsd"`

Si debe reemplazar
`"sdsdds 2022_-_02_-_18 sdsdsd"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No entiendo bien qué pretendías con la lambda, pero lo que estaba ocurriendo era lo siguiente.

Supongamos que la cadena de entrada contiene algo del tipo `<fecha> + <hora>`, entonces tu `identify_only_date_regex_00` encajará ambos campos. El resultado será un objeto `re.match()` con cuatro elementos que serán: `(<año>, <mes>, <dia>, <cadena de hora>)`

En ese caso tu lambda, ya que mira `if x.group(1)`, esa condición se cumplirá, ya que el primer elemento del grupo es no nulo (es el año), de modo que devolverá la cadena original sin reemplazar nada. Hasta aquí bien.

Pero seguidamente aplicas de nuevo un `re.sub()`, ahora con `identify_only_date_regex_01`, y en este caso **también** se genera un resultado con cuatro grupos, pero ahora el primer grupo que debería contener la hora, es nulo. Es decir, en este caso el grupo contiene `(None, <año>, <mes>, <dia>)`. De modo que en esta ocasión, dentro de la lambra, la condición `if x.group(1)` es `False` (pues `x.group(1)` vale `None`), por lo que en vez de retornar la cadena sin modificar, se realiza el reemplazo.

Una solución a este problema, cambiando mínimamente tu código, podría ser como sigue:

- Monta una expresión de captura que capture este formato: `<hora>? <fecha> <hora>?`. Es decir, la hora puede aparecer tanto al inicio como al final (como en ambos, aunque este caso no se dará).
- Ahora cada match va a tener cinco elementos: la hora que aparece delante, el año, mes y día y la hora que aparece detrás. Ahora bien, la hora de delante o la de detrás, o ambas, pueden ser nulas.
- Haz el reemplazo solo si ambas son nulas.

Este sería el código:

```
input_date_structure = r"(?P<year>\d*)_-_(?P<month>\d{2})_-_(?P<startDay>\d{2})"
time_structure = r"[\s|]*(\b\d{2}:\d{2}[\s|]*[ap]m)?[\s|]*"
regex = time_structure + input_date_structure + time_structure
date_restructuring_structure = r"\g<year>_-_\g<month>_-_\g<startDay>"

restructuring_only_date = lambda x: "(" + fr"{x.expand(date_restructuring_structure)}" + " 00:00 am)" \
                                     if not (x.group(1) or x.group(5)) else x.group()
input_text = re.sub(regex, restructuring_only_date, input_text)
```

### Demo

Input:

```
No debe reemplazar "sdsdds 2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am sdsddssd2
No debe reemplazar "sdsdsd 00:16 am 2022_-_02_-_19 sdsdsd"
Si debe reemplazar "sdsdds 2022_-_02_-_20 sdsdsd"
```

Output

```
No debe reemplazar "sdsdds 2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am sdsddssd2
No debe reemplazar "sdsdsd 00:16 am 2022_-_02_-_19 sdsdsd"
Si debe reemplazar "sdsdds(2022_-_02_-_20 00:00 am)sdsdsd"
```

Comment: Realmente muchas gracias por la ayuda. Lo de la lambda quizas no era necesario en este caso, pero estaba realizando los reemplazos dentro de funciones lambda por un tema de simple orden, pero supongo que podria evitarse almenos en este caso

Answer (score 1):

No nos has dicho con qué quieres reemplazar las fechas, por lo que simplemente las cambiare por "XXX".

El patrón para reconocer las fechas que no están junto a una hora es:

```
(?!(?:\d{2}:\d{2} (?:am|pm).))(\d{4}_-_\d{2}_-_\d{2}).(?!(?:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:am|pm)))
```

Está compuesto de tres partes:

- `(?!(?:\d{2}:\d{2} (?:am|pm).))` Reconoce cualquier cosa que no sea una hora. El prefijo `(?!` verifica que el texto **no** cumpla con la exp. reg. que sigue, efectivamente reconociendo cualquier cosa que no es una fecha.
- `(\d{4}_-_\d{2}_-_\d{2})` Reconoce y captura una fecha.
- `(?!(?:\d{2}:\d{2} (?:am|pm)))` Reconoce y captura otra hora (igual al primer patrón).

El prefijo `(?:...)` indica que el patrón se reconoce pero no se captura.

#### Demo

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r"(?!(?:\d{2}:\d{2} (?:am|pm).))(\d{4}_-_\d{2}_-_\d{2}).(?!(?:\d{2}:\d{2} (?:am|pm)))")
texto = "Alrededor de las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm 2022_-_02_-_18 , quizas cerca del 2022_-_02_-_18 llega el avion, pero no (2022_-_02_-_18 20:16 pm) a las (2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)"

print(patron.sub("XXX", texto))
```

produce

Alrededor de

```
 las 00:16 am o las 23:30 pm XXX, quizas cerca del XXXllega el avion, pero no (2022_-_02_-_18 20:16 pm) a las (2022_-_02_-_18 00:16 am), de esos hay dos (22)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @Candid_Moe Hola, como estas?, estaba intentando reordenarlas como ocurre en el output del ejemplo, en donde si no hay un horario delante o detras, se asuma que es el horario cero ( o sea 00:00 am de ese dia indicado), por lo que el reemplazo de `2022_-_02_-_18`  seria `(2022_-_02_-_18 00:00 am)` . Yo con ánimos de no sobresaturar de info innecesaria quizás me limite a indicar con el ejemplo, pero la idea del programa es asumir que si no se indica la hora detrás o delante de la fecha se asume que es hora cero de ese día (el inicio de dicho dia)

Comment: Por eso he usado los grupos de captura, ya que siento que es el mejor modo de extraer reemplazando en todas las coincidencias que halla en la cadena original. Solo por temas de organización les puse nombre a los grupos para referenciarlos como "etiquetas"

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez. Ya ves la importancia de plantear correctamente la pregunta, dando un ejemplo completo de las entradas y salidas esperadas.

Comment: Yo coloque el output que debería obtener junto al output erróneo, aun asi tienes razon, los datos de contexto ayudan aunque aveces se eviten para que no quede una pregunta con datos posiblemente irrelevantes o de color